# Indexação de DataFrame

Tags: r

Os dados seguem abaixo

`Prouni<-read.csv("C:\\cursos_prouni.csv")`
O seguinte link redireciona aos dados https://brasil.io/dataset/cursos-prouni/cursos.
Os dados são mostrados como na figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu peguei alguns dados, pois são 41447 linhas e 20 variáveis. Então selecionei 3.

`y <- data.frame(uf1=c("AC","AC","AC","AC","AC",
                      "AC","AC","AC","AC","AC","AC", "AC", 
                      "AL","AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
                      "AL","AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
                      "AL","AL", "AL", "AL", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
                      "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM"),
                cid=c("Acrelandia","Cruzeiro do Sul", "Cruzeiro do Sul",
                      "Cruzeiro do Sul", "Rio Branco","Rio Branco", 
                      "Rio Branco", "Rio Branco", "Rio Branco", "Rio Branco",
                      "Rio Branco", "Sena Madureira","Arapiraca", "Arapiraca", "Arapiraca",
                      "Delmiro Gouveia","Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", 
                      "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio",
                      "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Maceio", "Coari", 
                      "Itacoatiara","Jurua","Manaus","Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", 
                      "Manaus", "Manaus"), mensal=c(289.00,298.00,325.00,
                                                    319.00,298.00,823.22,476.00,
                                                    476.00,325.00,522.79,672.15,
                                                    250.00,298.00,586.63,290.35,
                                                    298.00,417.14,298.00,586.63,
                                                    669.00,669.00,169.00,464.31,
                                                    535.00,712.86,627.14,357.00,
                                                    548.00,366.90,209.00,312.90,
                                                    299.00,279.00,327.00,699.00, 
                                                    699.00,699.00,298.00,327.00, 
                                                    327.65))

y`

Com o seguinte código eu consigo identificar qual o curso que tem a maior mensalidade por UF `subset(y, y$mensal==max(mensal),)`. Só que queria mostrar todos os dados dos cursos mais caros de cada UF. 
Por exemplo, no AC na cidade tal, universidade, campus e etc a mensalidade é tanto (máximo) por cada `uf1`. Depois, no AL e no AM, por exemplo. No `Pyton` existe o comando `idxmax()`, onde ele localiza a linha onde a mensalidade é máxima por cada`uf1`. Existe alguma função parecida no `R`?

Comment: por favor, edite a sua pergunta colocando os dados através de dput(dados). Ainda, tente melhorar a sua pergunta basedata [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note que o resultado da sua pergunta em negrito, contempla uma diferente resposta do texto logo abaixo dela, desta forma, está ambígua.

Comment: o link que você colocou redireciona para uma página que contém vários datasets, favor colocar apenas o dataset que você quer em anexo, ou melhor ainda, coloque apenas o resultado de `dput(Prouni)`na sua pergunta, aí é mais fácil de resolvê-lá.
Sobre a pergunta em si, você quer o valor máximo da mensalidade agrupado pelas 7 primeiras colunas?

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer o que quer com a função R base `aggregate`.

```
fl <- list.files(pattern = "^cursos-prouni.*\\.csv$")

Prouni <- read.csv(fl)
str(Prouni)

fmla <- mensalidade ~ uf_busca + cidade_busca + universidade_nome + campus_nome
agg <- aggregate(fmla, data = Prouni, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Se preferir usar o pacote `dplyr`, poderá ser assim:

```
library(dplyr)

result1 <- Prouni %>%
  group_by(uf_busca, cidade_busca, universidade_nome, campus_nome) %>%
  summarise(Max = max(mensalidade, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Edição.**

Se quer agregar só por `uf_busca`, então é mais simples.

```
fmla2 <- mensalidade ~ uf_busca
agg2 <- aggregate(fmla2, data = Prouni, max, na.rm = TRUE)

result2 <- Prouni %>%
  group_by(uf_busca) %>%
  summarise(Max = max(mensalidade, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Com `dplyr` você pode fazer isso:

```
library(dplyr)

y %>% 
  group_by(uf1) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mensal)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

`group_by` faz a análise por grupo;

`arrange` ordena os dados de forma crescente ou decrescente (`desc`);

`slice` retorna apenas a primeira observação (a máxima) por grupo.